# Why can I only delete 5 of my questions per day?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, self-delete

I've thought better of more than 5 of my questions. They are better-suited to being answered outside SE. I started to delete them and discovered there was a 5-per-day limit. What is the motivation behind this limitation?

Comment: This is a system wide policy and I guess that you can better post this question on the main meta site. Probably there are already questions about it. I imagine that the restrictions exist to restrict potential malicious actions, like preventing people to destroy a large amount of questions which is a lot of work to undo. Similar restrictions exist for other actions, like there are limits to the amount of votes one can give and the amount of reputation that one can acquire.

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of this website is to create a durable repository of questions and answers, and destruction of useful content works against that purpose. You agreed to this when you created your account; when you posted on SE, you gave up
ownership of the content under
[CC BY-SA 4.0](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/licensing)

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I think my answer very clearly addresses the "motivation behind this limitation": **The purpose of this website is to create a durable repository of questions and answers**.

Comment: SE also has specifications on what constitutes "good" questions. Many of the questions I have asked do not meet these specifications, so their deletion is not counter-purpose.

Comment: In that very specific case of closed questions, I agree that deletion doesn’t harm the repository. However, it’s worth noting that closed questions with no answers with positive score  are automatically deleted after a certain period of time. So there’s no action needed from you to clean up closed questions — unless you would instead prefer to edit the question to improve it.